# Generic JS function working for Some divs, not for others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So a brief explanation of what this does: I have some html with several categories, I have two of those listed below, but there are normally five. Below is *registration* and *lobby*. I have several divs with pre-written responses for the user to click and I also have an add button so they can add in a new response.

At the bottom of each category is the `addResponses.html.twig` html. It contains the button to click, then a div drops down, the user enters their new response, hits *Enter* and it's added to the other divs, basically an exact replica.

`PROBLEM`: 
Currently, the problem is that it works great/as intended for the *registration*, but when I try to add responses to the other categories, such as *lobby*, it adds the `Div` but does not add the text.

`Html`:

```
<!-- Registration -->
<div class="row responses panel">
    <div class="small-12 column" data-category="a">
        <h3>Registration and Confirmation Email</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes"
            data-response-text="- No Time/Date on registration page"
            data-response-check="^a1"
            data-status-flag="1">
            No Time/Date on registration page
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes"
            data-response-text="- No registration page"
            data-response-check="^a1, ^a2, ^a3, ^a4, ^a5"
            data-status-flag="1">
            No registration page
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes"
            data-response-text="- Banner/Logo not displaying correctly"
            data-response-check=""
            data-status-flag="1">
            Banner/Logo not displaying correctly
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'QCBundle::Event/addResponses.html.twig' %}
</div>

<!-- Lobby -->
<div class="row responses panel">
    <div class="small-12 columns" data-category="b">
        <h3>Lobby</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes"
            data-response-text="- Time/Date not correct"
            data-response-check="^b1"
            data-status-flag="1">
            Time/Date not correct
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes"
            data-response-text="- Time/Date not listed"
            data-response-check="^b1"
            data-status-flag="1">
            Time/Date not listed
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes"
            data-response-text="- Banner/Logo not displaying correctly"
            data-response-check="^b1"
            data-status-flag="1">
            Banner/Logo not displaying correctly
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'QCBundle::Event/addResponses.html.twig' %}
</div>
```

`addResponses.html.twig`:

```
<div class="small-12 column">
    <div class="add-new-box">
        <div class="add-new">
            Add Response
        </div>
        <div class="add-new-text">
            <input class="text-response" type="text" placeholder="Response">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`JavaScript`:

```
var Add = {

onReady: function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".add-new", function() {

        // close other open text inputs
        $('.add-new-text').slideUp('normal');

        // if not open, then do so
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        }

        $(".text-response").focus();

    });

    // close junk on page load
    $('.add-new-text').hide();

},

addText: function() {

    $(".text-response").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var response= $(".text-response").val();
            var newHTML = '<div class="small-12 column">\
                                <div class="callout panel notes selected"\
                                  data-response-text="' + response + '"\
                                  data-response-check=""\
                                  data-status-flag="false">\
                                    <div class="remove-response"></div>\
                                    ' + response + '\
                                </div>\
                            </div>';
            $(newHTML).insertBefore( $(this).parents().eq(2) );
            $(".text-response").val('');
            $('.add-new-text').slideUp('normal');
        }
    });

},

removeText: function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".remove-response", function() {

        $(this).parents().eq(1).remove();


    });

}

};

$(document).ready(Add.onReady);
$(document).ready(Add.addText);
$(document).ready(Add.removeText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var response= $(".text-response").val();
```

should be:

```
var response= $(this).val();
```

Otherwise, you're always getting the value from the first `.text-response` field on the page, not the one that the user is filling in.

Comment: Great catch, thanks! I forgot about that context, changing it fixed the problem.